# How to batch convert legacy files to UTF8?

Tags: conversion, utf-8

I think the ideal solution for me is **a Nautilus Script that performs encoding conversion on selected files**.

The following script reads the encoding of a selected file and performs utf8 conversion if it's not utf8, but I couldn't figure out **how to make it work on multiple files**:

```
CHARSET="$(file -bi "$1"|awk -F "=" '{print $2}')"
if [ "$CHARSET" != utf-8 ]; then
iconv -f "$CHARSET" -t utf8 "$1" -c -o "$1.utf8"
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say your script is named `convert-to-utf-8.sh`. Here's how you would make it work across multiple files:

```
for filename in file1 file2 file3 ; do ./convert-to-utf-8.sh "$filename" ; done
```

You could incorporate that for-loop in the script itself, like this:

```
for filename in "$@"; do
    CHARSET="$(file -bi "$filename"|awk -F "=" '{print $2}')"
    if [ "$CHARSET" != utf-8 ]; then
        iconv -f "$CHARSET" -t utf8 "$filename" -c -o "$filename.utf8"
    fi
done
```

You could then run the script with multiple filenames like this:

```
./convert-to-utf-8.sh file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for teaching me this for-loop thing, it's magic! The revised code in the middle does exactly what I want!

Comment: But on second thought **is it possible to keep file extension intact?**

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it already and it seems inconv loses the input file (replaced by output file) before the operation is completed on longish files; and I get only half the file in the end.

Comment: @Sadi: you're right, here's how to fix that: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/how-can-i-make-iconv-replace-the-input-file-with-the-converted-output

Comment: Thank you so much! I've decided to show the result as a separate  answer so that it might be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice and simple **Nautilus Script** that I've managed to write thanks to [**Flimm**](https://askubuntu.com/users/2355/flimm) as seen in the answer above:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Nautilus Script to determine encoding of selected file(s) and convert to utf8 if necessary
#
for filename in $@; do
    CHARSET="$(file -bi "$filename"|awk -F "=" '{print $2}')"
    if [ "$CHARSET" != utf-8 ]; then
        iconv -f "$CHARSET" -t utf8 "$filename" -c -o "$filename.utf8" &&
        mv -f "$filename.utf8" "$filename"
    fi
done
```